# Process events as they are inserted using kotlin flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have this manager class that process events like this. Unfortunately it doesn't behave well when network state changes but an event is still being processed

```
fun init() {
    job = CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
        combine(
            networkMonitor.isOnline,
            fcmEventsRepository.getPendingFcmEvent()
        ) { isOnline, event ->
            isOnline to event
        }.collect { (isOnline, event) ->
            if (isOnline && event != null) {
                processEvent(event)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My process event function looks like this

```
private suspend fun processEvent(event: FcmEvent) = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        var success = false
        var retries = 0
        while (!success && isActive) {
            try {
                val isProcessed = fcmEventsRepository.isEventProcessed(event.id)
                if (isProcessed) return@withContext

                retryWithExponentialBackoff(
                    maxRetries = 5,
                    initialDelayMillis = 1000,
                    factor = 2,
                    action = {
                        syncRepository.syncByEventType(event.type)
                        fcmEventsRepository.updateFcmEventStatus(
                            event.id,
                            ProcessingStatus.Processed
                        )
                    }
                )
                success = true
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e, "Failed to process event $event, retrying in 1 minute...")
                delay(eventCheckDelay)
                retries++
            }
        }
}
```

How do I make sure that the event processing respects the following

- only a single event is processed at a time
- if the event is being processed and device lost connection processing is cancelled
- same event is not processed more that one if network state changes

Comment: With "if network state changes" in your last point, what do you mean? Network state here is only a Boolean and you want to cancel when it's false. How could it change from true to something else without you wanting to cancel it? If it weren't for that point, I would say all you need to do is change `collect` to `collectLatest`, and make sure `processEvent()` is a suspend function that supports cancellation. You might need to share the contents of that function if you're not sure what that means.

Comment: I have updated the question to include processEvent() function @Tenfour04

Comment: Network state cycles between true and false. If it goes to false I want to cancel the execution of processEvent() (If running) if it is true processEvent() can get executed @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

Your `processEvent` function already exits early if the event is already processed, so you don't need to worry about accidentally calling `processEvent` more than once on the same event if the connection state is lost and regained.

That just leaves cancelling previous processing when a new event arrives or the connection is lost. All you need to change to achieve that is replacing `collect` with `collectLatest`. When a new event or connection status arrives, it will cancel the previous processing and run the `collectLatest` lambda again.